# NoActionBar configuration still showing the action bar on Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I implemented the following code in my styles.xml file and passed it to my AndroidManifest but I can still see the action bar on an Android 13 Pixel 5 device. I have checked to see if I also have a styles-night.xml file, which I do not. As it is not my primary choice to call the getActionBar().hide() method in my Java code, is there a way to fix this?

[image]

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.Application" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see your screen action bar. It looks like what you expect When you remove android default action bar  you change end of .Light.DarkActionBar to Light.NoActionBar in theme and theme(night) xml file

Now i see your status bar in this screen

Comment: Thank you, but doesn't the color change at the top imply that the ActionBar is still there? In any case, is there a way to hide the light purple color in the styles.xml?

Comment: You said about statusBarColor color you might change it any time. When you want to change top type of screen let change statusBarColor item color in res>values>themes>themes.xml and themes.xml(night) files

Comment: Thank you for the help! Changing android:statusBarColor in the themes.xml worked for me. I thought that the issue was about the action bar, turns out I just forgot to change the color.

Comment: I am very happy to help for this problem. You said about statusBarColor in your head question. You may confused to understand statusBarColor and ActionBar. I think you learn full information these components on internet