# Jetpack Compose - Make the StatusBar transparent with it's content hidden

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm using `enableEdgeToEdge` to show contents under transparent status bar. Here is code snippet for the same:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    enableEdgeToEdge()
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContent {
        SampleApplicationTheme {
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
            ) {
                Image(
                    painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter("https://picsum.photos/seed/1234/700/2000"),
                    contentDescription = "Bucket Photo",
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how it looks on the screen

[image]

When I try to hide the status bar's content using `insetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars())`, it hides the status bar completely and moves the content below it vertically as shown here:

[image]

Is there a way to make hide status bar's content(and not status bar completely), so that I can utilise the whole screen for my content?

Comment: What do you mean by StatusBar content? can you elaborate?

Comment: @Chirag Thummar Wifi,5g,Battery icon and percentage.

Comment: If you want to Hide Those Icons then you need to make your app full screen using ````themes.xml`` or in ```Activity```.

Comment: @ChiragThummar Can you please provide a reference for that or any example?

Answer (score 0):

[Chirag Thummar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4649860/chirag-thummar)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78051757/jetpack-compose-make-the-statusbar-transparent-with-its-content-hidden#comment137600450_78051757) focuses on making the app full screen and making sure the status bar's content is hidden, effectively allowing the app's content to utilize the whole screen, including the area behind the status bar.

First, update your app theme in `themes.xml` to extend a `NoActionBar` theme and add flags to hide the status bar's content. If your app targets [Android API level 30](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history) (Android 11) or above, you can directly manipulate system bars' appearance in your theme. See "[Changing Android Studio's `NoActionBar` Theme to ActionBar: A Guide](https://copyprogramming.com/howto/how-to-change-a-theme-in-android-studio-from-noactionbar-to-actionbar)" by Shawn Gomez as an example.
And also "[`NoActionBar` configuration still showing the action bar on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76536549/6309)"

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Use this for Android 11 (API level 30) and above -->
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

In your [`Activity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity), apply additional configurations to make your app full screen and to hide the status bar icons. That step is important for Android versions below 11 (API level 30).

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
    val windowInsetsController = WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)
    windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars()) // Hide status bar icons
    windowInsetsController.systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE

    setContent {
        SampleApplicationTheme {
            // Your Compose content
        }
    }
}
```

It uses:

- `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)` makes sure your app's content can extend into the window insets area, making the app truly full screen. You can see it uses in [`google/accompanist` issue 1205](https://github.com/google/accompanist/issues/1205#issuecomment-1185598486).
- `windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars())` hides the status bar's content. Note that this method might not hide the status bar's background on all versions of Android, but it will make sure the icons and notifications are not visible, giving a more immersive experience.
- `windowInsetsController.systemBarsBehavior` is optional and allows the system bars to be shown temporarily when the user swipes from the edge of the screen. It enhances the user experience by allowing easy access to system bars in a full-screen app.

Answer (score 0):

In Theme.kt file remove following auto generated code

```
val view = LocalView.current
if (!view.isInEditMode) {
        SideEffect {
            val window = (view.context as Activity).window
            window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.primary.toArgb()
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = darkTheme
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).